# VBA Script pull data from website

Tags: vba, excel, data-extraction

I want to pull the data from http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/ to get the most recent prices of specific items.

I have an excel spreadsheet with the following:

```
|A | B
1 |Item |Price
2 |bfd/garden-structures/arches/premier-arches-pergola
```

and the VBA script:

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim item As String
item = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/" & item

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document
On Error Resume Next
output = doc.getElementByClass("NowValue").innerText
Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = output

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

i am new to VBA scripting and have no idea why it isnt pulling the value form the class "NowValue"

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `On Error Resume Next` line is stopping an error message from being displayed. That error message would be that there is no method on HTMLDocument called "getElementByClass". You probably want "getElementsByClassName" instead and will have to handle the fact that this returns a collection rather than a single element. Code like this would work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim item As String
item = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/" & item

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document

Dim results As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim result As IHTMLElement
Dim output As String

Set results = doc.getElementsByClassName("NowValue")
output = ""
For Each result In results
    output = output & result.innerText
Next result

Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = output

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

You would then find that there are multiple elements with class "NowValue" on that page. It looks as though the one you want might be enclosed in a div called "VariantPrice" so this code should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub bar()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim item As String
item = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/" & item

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document

Dim results As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim results2 As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim result As IHTMLElement
Dim result2 As IHTMLElement
Dim output As String

Set results = doc.getElementsByClassName("VariantPrice")
output = ""
For Each result In results
    Set results2 = result.getElementsByClassName("NowValue")
    For Each result2 In results2
        output = output & result2.innerText
    Next result2
Next result

Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = output

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

*edit:* as the code above works perfectly for me but fails to work for the question asker, it may be the case that they are using an older version of Internet Explorer which does not support `getElementsByClassName`. It may be the case that using `querySelector` will work instead. To be certain, go to [this QuirksMode page](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/accessingElements.html) to determine exactly what your browser supports.

New code using `querySelector`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub bar()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim result As IHTMLElement
Dim result2 As IHTMLElement
Dim item As String

item = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/" & item

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document

Set result = doc.querySelector(".VariantPrice")
Set result2 = result.querySelector(".NowValue")

Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = result2.innerText

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

*further edit:* to make the macro loop through all of the entries in column A, here are the relevant bits to add or change:

```
Option Explicit

Sub bar()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim result As IHTMLElement
Dim result2 As IHTMLElement
Dim item As String
Dim lRow As Long

ie.Visible = True
lRow = 2
item = Sheet1.Range("A" & lRow).Value

Do Until item = ""
    ie.navigate "http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/" & item

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set doc = ie.document

    Set result = doc.querySelector(".VariantPrice")
    Set result2 = result.querySelector(".NowValue")

    Sheet1.Range("B" & lRow).Value = result2.innerText

    lRow = lRow + 1
    item = Sheet1.Range("A" & lRow).Value   
Loop

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The page only has one instance of the class "NowValue" so i went with the first answer.  The script no longer works due to the line 'Set results = doc.getElementsByClassName("NowValue")', any ideas?

Comment: What error message are you getting? I've extended the code samples to be full procedures so you can see how the changes fit in. Also, the page [http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/bfd/garden-structures/arches/premier-arches-pergola](http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/bfd/garden-structures/arches/premier-arches-pergola) has four elements with class "NowValue" so you may well need the second version of the code

Comment: The error message says "Object doesn't support this property or method.

When I try the second one i also get the same error message.

Comment: You haven't by any chance put `doc.getElementByClassName` (i.e. singular element) instead of the correct  `doc.getElementsByClassName` (i.e. plural elements)? If in doubt, add a new module and copy/paste one of the sets of code from above (you might need to give the Sub a slightly different name) and see if that works

Comment: I used doc.getElementsByClassName which is what gave the error above. I'd be happy to sell my spreadsheet over to you to take a look? Thanks

Comment: You can upload the file to [https://www.hightail.com/u/barrowc](https://www.hightail.com/u/barrowc) and I'll take a look

Comment: Thanks, i have uploaded it now.

Comment: The Excel file you sent to me works perfectly for me with no modifications. I'll edit some further suggestions into my answer

Comment: Further Googling reveals that `getElementsByClassName` wasn't supported in Internet Explorer 8 or earlier so, if you are using one of those versions, that will be the problem. A different method called "querySelector" might work so I have included code for that as well

Comment: Hey! that was the issue thanks. It works perfectly for Cell A1 but doesn't seem to loop and do all of the instances in column A. How would i achieve this?

Comment: Thanks! Please could you provide me with the whole code as im confused where to add the most recent addition?

Comment: Thanks, i ran this and it came up with the error "compile error: variable not defined" and highlighted "output". I added "Dim output As Long" which ran the macro however all values were 0.

Comment: Sorry - output was carried over from the earlier versions of the code by mistake. I've now corrected it to use result2.innerText instead

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Random question: If i wanted to rename Sheet1 to 'Test' how would i change to vba code?

Comment: Also, for products which do not have discounts prices and therefore do not have the class now price and have a class called single price (e.g. http://www.buyshedsdirect.co.uk/grow-your-own/planters/compact-cascade-planter) how could i incorporate this into the code?

Comment: Replace every occurrence of `Sheet1` in the code with `Worksheets("Test")` so, for example, `item = Worksheets("Test").Range("A" & lRow).Value` For your other query, you would be better to ask a new question and include a link back to this question for context

Comment: Thanks! I have done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095995/vba-script-to-pull-values-within-specific-html-classes