# VBA script to pull values within specific HTML classes

Tags: html, vba, excel, if-statement

I created a VBA script to pull prices from websites by getting the value within an HTML Class.

Please see [VBA Script pull data from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943791/vba-script-pull-data-from-website) for more context.

This works really well however there are some cases where there is only 1 price (no RRP & sale price) and therefore i need to somehow incorporate an if statement to look for the a class name, if that doesn't exist look for another.

For example I have the following spreadsheet:

```
| A | B | C |
| | Item | Price |
| | bfd/garden-structures/arbours/arbours-sunflower | |
| | bfd/garden-structures/arbours/tatton-corner-arbour-seat | |
| | bsd/garden-storage/wooden-storage/4-x-2-windsor-garden-storage-chest | |
```

In this example the first 2 work with the code below: (looking int class `VariantPrice` & `NowValue`) however the 3rd example doesn't work as the classes `VariantPrice` & `NowValue` do not exist, however it does have the class `price` & `SinglePrice`.

The code I have used is below:

```
Sub BuyDeckingDirect()

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim result As IHTMLElement
    Dim result2 As IHTMLElement
    Dim item As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    'ie.Visible = True'
    lRow = 2
    item = Worksheets("BuyDeckingDirect").Range("B" & lRow).Value
    MsgBox "Price Dump Started"
    Do Until item = ""
        ie.navigate "http://www.buydeckingdirect.co.uk/" & item

        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Set doc = ie.document

        Set result = doc.querySelector(".VariantPrice")
        Set result2 = result.querySelector(".NowValue")

        Worksheets("BuyDeckingDirect").Range("C" & lRow).Value = result2.innerText

        lRow = lRow + 1
        item = Worksheets("BuyDeckingDirect").Range("B" & lRow).Value

    Loop
    MsgBox "BuyDeckingDirect Price Dump Complete"
End Sub
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Jess

Answer (score 1):

Combine both classes in the call to `querySelector` and if `result` is `Nothing`, call it again with the alternative class.

Example:

```vb
' ...
Set result = doc.querySelector(".VariantPrice .NowValue")
If result Is Nothing Then
    Set result = doc.querySelector(".VariantPrice .price")
End If
' You should consider the fact that you can have neither
If result Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets(...etc...).Value = "N/A"
Else
    Worksheets(...etc...).Value = result.innerText
End If
```

Of course you can also check for the existence of the `NowValue` class after setting `result` like so:

```vb
' ...
Set result = doc.querySelector(".VariantPrice")
If IsNull(result.querySelector(".NowValue")) Then
    Set result2 = result.querySelector(".price")
Else
    Set result2 = result.querySelector(".NowValue")
End If
```

Personally, I prefer the 1st option but it's up to your use case.